# Как рекурсивно обработать JSON?

Tags: javascript, jquery

От сервера приходит ответ, вложенность дочерних элементов может любая. Нужно вывести список с вложенными элементами. Попробовал рекурсивно обработать ответ, но получаю ошибку "forEach is not a function"при вычислении вложенного массива.

код:

```
let response = [{
        "isparent": true,
        "name": "Тестовое 1",
        "objectid": "fb27a8af-5675-40a7-a717-35f31743787b",
        "child": [{
            "isparent": true,
            "name": "Тестовое 11",
            "objectid": "fb27a8af-5675-40a7-a717-35f31743787b",
            "child": [{
                "isparent": false,
                "name": "Тестовое 12",
                "objectid": "fb27a8af-5675-40a7-a717-35f31743787b",
                "child": []
            }]
        }]
    },
    {
        "isparent": false,
        "name": "Тестовое 6",
        "objectid": "d00e93d6-5cdc-4c0a-a39d-bd86c9de9f13"
    },
    {
        "isparent": false,
        "name": "Тестовое 7",
        "objectid": "4b2f28b2-dd5c-4075-a2fc-d3459ad4294e",
        "child": []
    },
    {
        "isparent": false,
        "name": "Тестовое 14",
        "objectid": "d237bc0f-ab13-4e3f-9cac-ca38f43e9ac7",
        "child": []
    },
    {
        "isparent": true,
        "name": "Тестовое 15",
        "objectid": "35e3e74d-912e-452a-a7af-dd54c82018b9",
        "child": [{
            "isparent": false,
            "name": "Тестовое 89",
            "objectid": "fb27a8af-5675-40a7-a717-35f31743787b",
            "child": []
        }]


    }
]

function getStruct(data) {
  let retstr = '';


  data.forEach(function (item) {
  let children = item.child
  if(item.isparent){
    retstr += '<li><span class="open-child">+</span><span class="caret" data-objectId="' + item.objectid + '">' + item.name + '</span><ul>'
   children.forEach(value=>{
      retstr += getStruct(value);
    });
    retstr += '</ul></li>';
  } else {
    retstr += '<li>'+item.name+'</li>';
  }

  });

  return retstr;
}

let result = getStruct(response);
$('.result').html(result)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

не нужно было вызывать второй раз обработку массива

```
function getStruct(data) {
  let retstr = '';


  data.forEach(function (item) {
  let children = item.child
  if(item.isparent){
    retstr += '<li><span class="open-child">+</span><span class="caret" data-objectId="' + item.objectid + '">' + item.name + '</span><ul>'
      retstr += getStruct(value);
    retstr += '</ul></li>';
  } else {
    retstr += '<li>'+item.name+'</li>';
  }

  });

  return retstr;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Проблема вот тут:

```js
   children.forEach(value=>{
      retstr += getStruct(value);
    });
```

Когда вы вызываете `getStruct`, то даёте не массив, а объект. `getStruct` в свою очередь ждёт массив, так как пробует выполнить `data.forEach`.